# Using SFTP in Java, How do I transfer a file from one folder to another?

Tags: java, sftp, jsch

I have a simple directory with two folders -

[image]

In the `SFTP_1` folder, I have a bitmap image.  And the `SFTP_2` folder is just an empty folder.

Does Java have a native SFTP library to use? When I searched I only found a library online called [JSch](http://www.jcraft.com/jsch/).

How would I get started to run this example? 
Any tips appreciated, 
thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's no native SFTP support in Java.

The JSch library, you have found, is probably the most widely used SFTP implementation for Java *(Though the original JSch is not maintained anymore and it is not compatible with up-to-date servers. Consider using [mwiede's fork](https://github.com/mwiede/jsch) instead).*

---

If you want to move the file from the `SFTP_1` to the `SFTP_2` using JSch, use the [`ChannelSftp.rename` method](https://epaul.github.io/jsch-documentation/javadoc/com/jcraft/jsch/ChannelSftp.html#rename-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-):

```
channelSftp.rename("/SFTP_1/file.txt", "/SFTP_2/file.txt");
```

---

If you want to copy the file, it's more complicated. While there's the [`copy-file` extension to the SFTP protocol](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-secsh-filexfer-extensions-00#section-6), it's supported by only a few SFTP servers. In the most widespread OpenSSH SFTP server it is supported only by very recent [version 9.0](https://www.openssh.com/txt/release-9.0). And it's not supported by the JSch library either.

So in the end, your only option is probably to download the file to a local temporary folder and upload it back to the new location (or use streams, to avoid a temporary file). Or use shell session to invoke a command like `cp`. See also

- [How do I transfer a file from one directory to another using Java SFTP Library JSch?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32787456/850848)
- [How do I copy files stored in a remote SFTP server to another folder in the same remote server using Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45004008/850848)

Answer (score 1):

SFTP supports RenameFile and CopyRemoteFile operations but only starting from SFTP protocol version 5 or 6 if memory serves. Our product, SecureBlackbox (Java edition), supports these operations, however it is necessary to ensure that your server supports the required SFTP version and thus the file operations you need.