# Copying files internally on an SFTP server using Spring integration/JCraft JSch

Tags: java, spring, copy, sftp, jsch

I was wondering if there is a way to copy files on an SFTP server to another directory on the same SFTP server. I want to do this without getting the file in a client and then setting it in the other folder. Of course this would work fine but I guess that this would produce more overhead, so I would like to avoid this if at all possible. I'm currently working with Spring integration which is based on JCraft JSch.

So far I haven't been able to find any way to do this without an intermediary.

Another approach would be to open an SSH channel and just use the `cp` command but well that's not too pretty either in my opinion.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A core SFTP protocol does not support duplicating a remote file.

There's a draft of [`copy-file` extension to the protocol](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-secsh-filexfer-extensions-00), but that's supported by only few SFTP servers ([ProFTPD `mod_sftp`](http://www.proftpd.org/docs/contrib/mod_sftp.html) and Bitvise SFTP server for example).

In the most widespread OpenSSH SFTP server it is supported only by very recent [version 9.0](https://www.openssh.com/txt/release-9.0).

And it's also not supported by the JSch library.

---

See also my answer to [How can I copy/duplicate a file to another directory using SFTP?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28089821/850848)

---

So actually using the `cp` shell command over an "exec" channel ([`ChannelExec`](https://epaul.github.io/jsch-documentation/javadoc/com/jcraft/jsch/ChannelExec.html)) is unfortunately the best available approach (assuming you connect to a *nix server and you have a shell access).

---

If you do not have a shell access, then your only option is indeed to download the file to a local temporary folder and upload it back to the new location (or use streams, to avoid a temporary file). See also:

- [How do I transfer a file from one directory to another using Java SFTP Library JSch?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32787456/850848)
- [How do I copy files stored in a remote SFTP server to another folder in the same remote server using Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45004008/850848)

Comment: Thanks for your awnser. It's a shame that its not supported. It seems such a trivial task :)