# How do I copy files stored in a remote SFTP server to another folder in the same remote server using Java?

Tags: java, sftp, jsch

I have been trying to copy few selected files (after performing few checks), in a remote server to the same remote server using:

```
File localFile = new File(srcPath);
sftpChannel.put(localFile.getAbsolutePath(),localFile.getName());
```

I have even tried to copy those selected files to my local machine using the `get()` method.

Can somebody help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A core SFTP protocol does not support duplicating a remote file.

There's draft of [`copy-file`/`copy-data` extensions to the protocol](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-secsh-filexfer-extensions-00). But those are supported by only few SFTP servers. In the most widespread OpenSSH SFTP server it is supported only by very recent [version 9.0](https://www.openssh.com/txt/release-9.0). Other servers are for example [ProFTPD `mod_sftp`](http://www.proftpd.org/docs/contrib/mod_sftp.html) and Bitvise SFTP server.

The JSch library does not support the extensions.

Alternatives:

- If you have a shell access, open an "exec" channel, and use shell `cp` command (or equivalent command for your server's OS).
  See [`Exec.java` example](http://www.jcraft.com/jsch/examples/Exec.java.html).
- Otherwise, your only option is to download the file to a local temporary location and upload its copy back to a different/target remote directory. Or [use streams](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32787456/850848#32846604), to avoid a temporary file.

See also [How can I copy/duplicate a file to another directory using SFTP?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28089821/850848)